# Set PATH params to HttpRequest

Tags: java, http, servlets

I am trying to create a simple HttpServer in Java using com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer to handle GET and POST requests.  I would like to know what is the best way (if there is one) to create a context for a URI accepting PATH params in the URL. For example, I'd like to accept a request like /4/price, but I cannot do that dynamically using

```
public abstract HttpContext createContext(String path)
```

because it only excepts Strings and not regular expressions. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
server.createContext("/{productTypeId}/price", new PriceHandler());
```

Below the code I've written so far:

```
public App() throws IOException {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);
        server.createContext("/product", new ProductHandler());
        server.createContext("/productType", new ProductTypeHandler());

        server.createContext("/{productTypeId}/price", new PriceHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
        server.start();
        System.out.println("\nRunning! Point your browsers to http://localhost:8080/ \n");
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Create a context for "/", and parse the URI in your handler.

Comment: That implies to have only one handler for all requests and to decide based on the path if calling a service or another. Am I right?

Comment: I.e  if(path.equals('/product')) productService.getProduct(); And that for every service, right?